# Form1 does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, constructor

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;
    public Form1(Form2 form_2)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = form_2;
    }



private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form2.textBox1.Text = "test";
    }
```

And after this I am facing the **Form1 does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments** error. What can be the reason for this error?

Comment: Your `Form1` class should have an empty constructor. You have only one constructor and it requires parameter of type `Form2`.

Comment: Does anyone every bother to actually *read* the error message anymore or is it just an insta-post to SO when you get a compiler error? Oh well, I guess it's questions like this that help people raise their reputation score.

Comment: where and how is form1 and form2 instantiated ?

Answer (score 3):

Create a parameterless constructor like

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```